# How to get the total count from each date in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How to get the total count for particular date by selecting different dates.
For Example: 
Record contains from '2014-04-01' to till date. Each date contains multiple records with different IST time.

How to get the total count from each date?

Comment: put some sample code and expected output. so other can understand.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your table structure and result you want, Query should look somewhat like this

```
  SELECT DATE(date_column), COUNT(*) 
    FROM tablename 
   WHERE date_column IN (your_date_list)
GROUP BY date(date_column);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following `sql` (I have not tested)

```
 SELECT date_column, COUNT(*) 
 FROM tablename 
 WHERE date_column BETWEEN date_column AND current_date
 GROUP BY to_date(date_column::text,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Converting a `date` column to a string and then converting it back to a `date` does not make any sense (plus it's really bad coding style because you rely on implicit date formatting). If you want to remove a potential time part from a `timestamp` column you should use `date_trunc()` or cast the `timestamp` to a `date` (see chetan's answer). Plus: you need to use the same expression in the select list as you use in the `group by` clause.